# JS remove element from array with no gap

Tags: javascript

```
var myList = [];
myList.push({ololo: "ololo0"});
myList.push({ololo: "ololo1"});
myList.push({ololo: "ololo2"});
console.log(myList);
```

**Result:**

```
[Object { ololo="ololo0"}, Object { ololo="ololo1"}, Object { ololo="ololo2"}]
```

**Question**: How do I delete the second (`myList[1]`) element with no gap where it was?
**I.e this:**

```
myList[0] = {ololo: "ololo0"}
myList[1] = {ololo: "ololo1"}
myList[2] = {ololo: "ololo2"}
```

**Should be:**

```
myList[0] = {ololo: "ololo0"}
myList[1] = {ololo: "ololo2"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myList = [];
myList.push({ololo: "ololo0"});
myList.push({ololo: "ololo1"});
myList.push({ololo: "ololo2"});
console.log(myList);

console.log(remove(myList,1));


function remove(arr, index){
    arr.splice(index,1);
    return arr;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/qzFuj/

Comment: Note, that it works in linear time - it is equivalent to making a new array and copying all the items into it, omitting the deleted one.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javascript-array-remove-element-js-array-delete-element/

you can use this function below

```
function removeByIndex(arr, index) {
   arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

here's how to use it

```
   var mynewArray =  removeByIndex(myList,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Delete wont do the trick. But Array.splice will do the trick.

myList.splice(index, 1)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> `array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])`
>
> Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing
>   old elements.

For removing the second element: `myList.splice(1, 1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you Expect and what you want

**if you use `splice` it suits you**

```
var myList = [];
myList.push({ololo: "ololo0"});
myList.push({ololo: "ololo1"});
myList.push({ololo: "ololo2"});

  ///////////////////////splice IS APPLIED////////////////////////////
    myList.splice(0, 1)
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

console.log(myList);
```

**output** (note that index 0 is completely Removed!)

```
[Object { ololo=

"ololo1"

}, 
Object { ololo=

"ololo2"

}]
```

**if you use `delete` ,it wont suite you ! here is what it looks!**

```
  var myList = [];
    myList.push({ololo: "ololo0"});
    myList.push({ololo: "ololo1"});
    myList.push({ololo: "ololo2"});

  ////////////////DELETE IS APPLIED///////////////////////////////////
    delete myList[0]
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    console.log(myList);
```

**output : (mainly look on undefined at index 0)**

```
    [

    undefined

    , Object { ololo=

    "ololo1"

    }, Object { ololo=

    "ololo2"

    }]
```